# How to install latest IPython in Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: software-installation, ipython

I want to install `ipython` with latest version 6.X

1. I used command `pip install ipython`, but after it installed successfully, I typed `ipython` in terminal then it said "ipython is not currently installed"
2. Then I installed it using `sudo apt-get insatall ipython` and checked the version using `ipython --version`: it shows 2.4.1.

So, how can I get ipython with latest version?

Comment: `pip` isn't usually used for Ubuntu software installs - which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: i am using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS